# Hamburger menu with master/details view and a bindable object in UWP app

Tags: windows, data-binding, observablecollection, uwp

I am creating a Windows 10 UWP app with a hamburger menu and master/detail view. I have got this part done.

Now I want to have an observable collection in the master list pane so that I can add new items to the master list dynamically. How do I achieve this?

I have used the [**hamburger menu**](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-021-Implementing-a-Simple-Hamburger-Navigation-Menu) used by Bob taylor from channel9 and added the [**master/detail**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail) sample from Microsoft inside a frame in the split view content like this:

```
<SplitView.Content><Frame x:Name="sumname"/></SplitView.Content>
```

And in the MainPage constructor I navigate the MasterDetailPage to this frame.

Comment: The AppUIBasics sample should answer that question; see SplitViewPage.xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `ListView` in the `SplitView.Pane` and bind the `ListView` to the collection.

ListView is an ItemsControl, so it can contain a collection of items of any type. To populate the view, add items to the Items collection, or set the ItemsSource property to a data source.For more info, see  [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx).

A common scenario is to bind to a collection of business objects. In C# and Visual Basic, the generic ObservableCollection class is a good collection choice for data binding. For more info, see [Binding to a collection of items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt269383.aspx#binding_to_collections).

In XAML:

```xml
<SplitView.Pane>
 <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Menus}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Menu">
             <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}"></TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
</SplitView.Pane>
```

In the code behind:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
 this.InitializeComponent();
 ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
}

public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
 Menu menu = ((sender as ListView).SelectedItem as Menu);
 MyFrame.Navigate(menu.NavigateTo);
}
```

Menu.cs code:

```
public class Menu 
{
public string Title { get; set; }

public Type NavigateTo { get; set; }

public Menu(string title,Type navigateTo)
{
    this.Title = title;
    this.NavigateTo = navigateTo;
}
```

MainPageViewModel.cs code:

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
 public ObservableCollection<Menu> Menus;
 public MainPageViewModel()
 {
     Menus = new ObservableCollection<Menu>()
    {
          new Menu("Page1",typeof(Page1)),
          new Menu("Page2",typeof(Page2)),
          new Menu("Page3",typeof(Page3))
    };
 }
}
```

Comment: I went for MVVM Style in the end.. Thanks for your answer!